# tooltips of a scaled jquery flot chart appear in wrong position

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, flot.tooltip

I'm using the [flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) library

How do I get the correct tooltips if I scale the chart with this css rule: `transform: scale(0.7);`

flot source uses the function `findNearbyItem` to find hovered items.

[[**FIDDLE**]](http://jsfiddle.net/hhxyy4t9/) that demonstrates both cases - *scale(1), and scale(.7)*

Comment: could you please elaborate your question a bit more, what do you mean with getting "plothover right" ?

Answer (score 1):

taking your fiddle as source of the question, there is actually several problems to take care of:

1. the tooltip doesn't work correctly, if you hover over the tooltip, it disappears (starts flickering). Check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhxyy4t9/8/), which now hides the tooltip if you move away from the bar and stays if you hover over the tooltip itself.
2. scaling issue: just scale the canvas wrapper.

   ```
   <div id="placeholder2" style="width:420px;height:210px;margin-top:40px;"></div>
   ```

   scales the canvas to the same size like the css transform

   ```
   <div id="placeholder2" style="transform:scale(.7)"></div>
   ```

   but maintains the correct bar values and shows the tooltip in the correct position.

Comment: yes, thank you, i know it works if only canvas is scaled, but the situation is specific - scaled is the whole body using css.

I found the solution, and had to modify plugin source. never trust `$.offset` ^^